# how to play .aac files with open al for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to design a game for the iPhone that requires spacial (stereo) audio. I found open al, but it seems that the only built in formats supported on the iPhone is pcm. However, this is far too big for my project. For example, I have a simple game with approximately 5 sounds, no images, and nothing else. However, the size is 45 mb, because all the files are pcm (uncompressed) audio. I found that .aac files can be decoded in hardware, which I hear is much faster than software decoding. However, I can't find any documentation on how to use .aac files with open al. Any help in pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.
Thanks,
-Michael.

Comment: Note that hardware decoding can occur only for one file at a time. That means there is only one hardware decoder available which can handle only one file at any time. If you play multiple files then all remaining files will be decoded in software.